# Minimal 64-bit Windows executable crashes with tail-call optimization enabled by gcc

Tags: c, windows, assembly, gcc, x86

I'm trying to create a minimal 64-bit Windows executable to better understand how the Windows executable format works.

I wrote very basic assembly and C code as follows.

**hi.s**

```
    section .text

hi:
    db "hi", 0

    global sayHi
    align 16
sayHi:
    lea rax, [rel hi]
    ret
```

**start.c**

```
extern int puts();
extern const char *sayHi();

void start() {
    puts(sayHi());
}
```

compiled with,

```
nasm -fwin64 hi.s
gcc -c -ostart.obj -O3 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls start.c
# I will explain the flag
```

and linked with,

```
golink /fo r.exe /console start.obj hi.obj msvcrt.dll
# create a console application `r.exe`
# the default entry point is `start`
```

The program runs fine and prints `hi`, but note the `gcc` flag `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`. That flag disables tail-call optimizations so that the program always allocates stack space and `call`s a function. Without the flag, the program crashes.

This is the disassembled result without tail-call optimization. Not sure why `gcc` put a `nop` there, but otherwise it's very simple and runs fine.

```
0000000000401000 <.text>:
  401000:   48 83 ec 28             sub    rsp,0x28
  401004:   e8 27 00 00 00          call   0x401030 # sayHi
  401009:   48 89 c1                mov    rcx,rax
  40100c:   e8 ff 2f 00 00          call   0x404010 # puts
  401011:   90                      nop
  401012:   48 83 c4 28             add    rsp,0x28
  401016:   c3                      ret    
  ...
  401020:   68 69 00 90 90          push   0xffffffff90900069 # "hi"
  ...
  401030:   48 8d 05 e9 ff ff ff    lea    rax,[rip+0xffffffffffffffe9] # 0x401020
  401037:   c3                      ret
```

This is when tail-call opt is enabled, in which the program crashes.

```
0000000000401000 <.text>:
  401000:   48 83 ec 28             sub    rsp,0x28
  401004:   e8 27 00 00 00          call   0x401030 # sayHi
  401009:   48 89 c1                mov    rcx,rax
  40100c:   48 83 c4 28             add    rsp,0x28
  401010:   e9 eb 2f 00 00          jmp    0x404000 # puts
  ...
  401020:   68 69 00 90 90          push   0xffffffff90900069 # "hi"
  ...
  401030:   48 8d 05 e9 ff ff ff    lea    rax,[rip+0xffffffffffffffe9] # 0x401020
  401037:   c3                      ret
```

Now the program doesn't allocate stack space before `puts` and simply does a `jmp` instead of `call`.

I investigated further to see where exactly it jumps when calling `puts`.

In the no-tail-call case, the called address `0x404010` in the `.idata` section has the instruction `jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffffffffffea] # 0x404000`, and `0x404000` seems to contain the address to `puts`.

However in the tail-call case, the called address `0x404000` has `54 40 00 00` which is no meaningful instruction. The debugger says the program segfaults at `0x404003`, so I'm pretty sure the program chokes trying to execute a garbage instruction.

I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure which, so could you explain why the tail-call case fails and how to get it work?

Comment: Seems strange; what GCC version are you compiling with?  Presumably something to do linker options, since your asm and GCC's asm both look fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes `gcc version 11.2.0 (Rev8, Built by MSYS2 project)`, `Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32`. Hmm, okay, so I'll try with different linker options or maybe a different linker. Btw, do you know how to link similarly with GNU `ld`?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, you were correct. It was a linker problem.. `ld -or.exe start.obj hi.obj msvcrt.dll` seems to work fine with a copy of `msvcrt.dll` from the system folder. I just need to find a way to set `console`/`gui` mode.

Comment: I have no idea about Windows toolchain details.  I know some things about Windows, like the calling conventions, but this is not one of them.

Comment: @PeterCordes `--subsystem=console/windows`, `--subsystem ...`, or `-subsystem=...` all seem to work for GNU `ld`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please write an answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on `golink` not correctly handling tail-calls. I searched a while to make GNU `ld` link the program with the same options given to `golink`.

You can create a console-mode Windows executable by GNU `ld` with this command.

```
ld -o... --subsystem=console object-files...
```

`--subsystem console` or `-subsystem=console` also means the same. Use `--subsystem=windows` to create a GUI application.

GNU `ld` also handles Windows `dll` files, so in this case, simply giving `ld` a copy of `msvcrt.dll` from the system folder worked.